# If $\tau\in\Bbb R\setminus\Bbb Z$ then $\sum_{n-\infty}^\infty{1\over(\tau+n)^2} = {\pi^2\over\sin^2(\pi\tau)}$ holds?

Tags: complex-analysis, fourier-analysis

The following is Exercise 4.7 of Stein's complex analysis.

> The Poisson summation formula applied to specific examples often provides interesting identities.Let $\tau$ be fixed with $\operatorname{Im}(\tau)>0$. Apply the Poisson summation formula to
> $$f(z) = (\tau+z)^{-k},$$
> where $k$ is an integer $\geq 2$, to obtain
> $$\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty{1\over(\tau+n)^k} = {(-2\pi i)^k\over(k-1)!}\sum_{m=1}^\infty m^{k-1}e^{2\pi im\tau}.$$
> Set $k =2$ in the above formula, if $\operatorname{Im}(\tau)>0$, then
> $$\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty{1\over(\tau+n)^2} = {\pi^2\over\sin^2(\pi\tau)}.$$
> **Question**. Can one conclude that the above formula holds true whenever $\tau$ is any complex number that is not an integer?

For the $\operatorname{\tau}>0$ case, I used residue theorem with lower half circle to derive the formula. Similarly, residue theorem with upper half circle shows the formula
$$\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty{1\over(\tau+n)^2} = {\pi^2\over\sin^2(\pi\tau)}.$$
holds for $\operatorname{Im}(\tau)<0$. But I can't use such a strategy for the $\tau\in\Bbb R\setminus\Bbb Z$ case. I know the formula holds for any $\tau\in\Bbb C\setminus\Bbb Z$. In fact (Exercise 3.12), it can be proved using the residue theorem on the function
$$f(z) ={\pi\cot\pi z\over (\tau+z)^2}$$
but is there a way to prove the case $\tau\in\Bbb R\setminus\Bbb Z$ besides this? Or does the exercise just want me to refer the previous exercise problem?

Comment: Analytic continuation (w.r.t. $\tau$)?

Comment: @metamorphy Oh. Thank you